# Tell UITableView to not release cell when not visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Is there any method to tell a UITableView to *not* release cells when they become not visible?

I'm asking this because I have this problem:
I have an UITableView used as an "insert View". Inside the cells I have many UITextViews. When I push the UITableView, I send "becomeFirstResponder" to the first cell, to start the view with the keyboard opened. This works correctly.

But, If I scroll down, when the first cell become not visible, the keyboard close itself.
Note: the UITextView associated is a property retain and it correctly remains allocated, simply the cell disappear and the UITextView seems to resign first responder.

I know that I can check when the UITextView comes back visible and send another becomeFirstResponder, but I'd like to know if I can reach my goal with the first request :-)

Thank you
Regards
Fabio

Comment: You might want to lock scrolling when soft keyboard is opened. Mobile devices have limited memory. It's technically impossible for them to keep the cells off screen. And if you did manage to keep them, your app will be killed due to excessive use of memory.

Comment: Agree with @HeShiming.  Also, your users probably don't want to enter text into a field they cannot see.

Comment: @HeShiming we are talking about an "insert view", the number of cells is limited :-) Obviously I have to take care about the memory, but I already do this (not using ARC in this APP)...I'm very careful about memory :-D. Good the idea to lock scrolling both with danh consideration about writing inside an invisible textview :-D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some new informations I've found:

I saw that the Keyboard was closing only the first time. Example: The view was loaded with the UITextView as the firstResponder. Scrolling, the keyboard would close.
But, after tapping on the UITextView again, the keyboard would open again and then never close, even if scrolling again.

Looking for understanding the reason, I discovered this:

- In the "viewDidLoad" I was setting the first responder
- in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I was adding the UITextView as a subview
- the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called after the ViewDidLoad

When the UITextView was resigning first responder, I saw that it was happening because the UITableView was searching for that particular cell calling the CellForRowAtIndexPath method.
But, After tapping again, the CellForRowAtIndexPath was called only for other cells, not the selected one. It seemed that, if the UITextView was setted as the first responder AFTER the UITableView setup, the cell was retained even if not visible.

Then, I tried to move the "becomefirstresponder" in the "viewDidAppear" (called AFTER the uitableview setup) and then, magically, the problem was solved :-)
The cell is no more released if the UITextView inside is the first responder.

The only remaining problem was this: calling "becomeFirstResponder" in the viewDidApper cause a lag in the keyboard to show on the screen. To avoid this, I called becomeFirstResponder in viewDidLoad, then in viewDidAppear I resigned and called again becomeFirstResponder.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

while using tableview in cell usually it wont release cell. First time it will allocate some number of cells which are visible first time table appears, after that it uses same cells means reuses same cell for different date at different indexpath , you should have used
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: No, I removed it. The UITableview is not dequeuing the cell for reusing, but it's simply releasing the cell that are not visible (this is by design and correct). I was asking if there was any "magic method" to avoid this, obviously only in this specific case. Thanks

Comment: when you alloc the cell you may have used autorelease, which will make the cell to release it self by the operating system, so try it with out autorelease